# Primefaces multi file selection not working in IE11 browser

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, weblogic12c, mojarra

I am trying to  implement multi file upload using primefaces5.2 in IE11 browser, but its not allowing me to select more than one file at once.

The same stuff is working perfectly in chrome browser.

Jars Configured:

> javax.faces.jar(JSF2.1.9),Primefaces5.2.jar ,Weblogic 12c

Web.xml :

```
<web-app>
  <servlet>
     <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
     <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
     <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <context-param>
    <description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default). See JSF Specification 2.5.2</description>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>client</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.UPLOADER</param-name>
    <param-value>auto</param-value>
</context-param>
 <filter>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
<filter-class> org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter
</filter-class>
 </filter>
 <filter-mapping>
   <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
   <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
 </filter-mapping>
<listener>
<listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

fileUpload.xhtml :

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
 </h:head>
<h:body>
     <h:form enctype="multipart/form-data" >
            <p:fileUpload value="#{fileUploadBean.file}" mode="advanced" multiple="true"
                            fileUploadListener="#{fileUploadBean.fileUploadListener}"></p:fileUpload>
    </h:form>
  <h:body>
 </html>
```

FileUploadBean.java

```
 @ManagedBean
 @SessionScoped
 public class FileUploadBean {
    UploadedFile file;

    public UploadedFile getFile() {
    return file;
     }

    public void setFile(UploadedFile file) {
     this.file = file;
     }

   public void fileUploadListener(FileUploadEvent e){
    // Get uploaded file from the FileUploadEvent
    this.file = e.getFile();
    // Print out the information of the file
    System.out.println("Uploaded File Name Is :: "+file.getFileName()     +" ::    Uploaded File Size :: "+file.getSize());
    }
```

Comment: which browser do you use?

Comment: @ErkanErol  I am testing this code on IE11 browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In IE 11 my web application is in compatibility mode, I removed web application from compatibility mode and now I am able to select multiple files.

Answer (score 1):

Please remove the value attribute. In advance mode, Primefaces calls the listener for each file and the value is not necessary.

```
  <p:fileUpload  mode="advanced" multiple="true" 
      fileUploadListener="#{fileUploadBean.fileUploadListener}">
  </p:fileUpload>
```

You should use a list instead of a single file

```
ArrayList<UploadedFile> files = new ArrayList<UploadedFile>();
```

and in the method add the file to the list

```
files.add(e.getFile());
```

Also, be sure that SessionScoped is the best scope for you. Because, most of time using ViewScoped is better.

Comment: removed the value attribute but no change, I am unable to select multiple files at once. Is it works on IE11?

Comment: Could you change the param UPLOADER from auto to common?

Comment: I tried that option also, but still its not working(context param value is **commons**).

Comment: I am able to select only single file at once(in order to upload several files, I am clicking on  file selection button several times).In this scenario I am able to upload multiple files, but multiple files selection at once is which I have to implement is not working.

Comment: To able to select multiple files at once, "multiple" attribute has to be set in the generated html outputs. However I don't understand why the code doesn't work.

Comment: I  configured jars JSF2.1.9 not JSF2.2 as mentioned in actual question. We are using weblogic 12c server and JSF2.2 is not supported by Weblogic 12c server at the moment. I have deployed same code with JSF2.2+PrimeFaces5.2 in Tomcat7 server and multi file upload is working in IE10 browser with degraded performance and not working in IE11 browser(Feeling Strange). does JSF2.1.9 +primefaces5.2 support multi file upload capability?.